# Which are the possible hyperparameters with GridSearchcv and also if activation function does not exist can I add it?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

I am performing predictions with Keras and time series. I am facing a problem when performing GridSearchCV snd especially with the activation function in hyperparameter tuning. I am giving you my code and the output. That's my first func:

```
def model_selection(prediction_model, T, HORIZON, units = 50, activation = 'relu', epochs = 1, optimizer = 'RMSprop'):
    model = Sequential()
    #prediction_model = 'LSTM'
    if prediction_model == 'GRU':
        model.add(GRU(units = units, input_shape = (T, 1), activation = activation))
    elif prediction_model == 'LSTM':
        model.add(LSTM(units = units, input_shape = (T, 1), activation = activation))
    elif prediction_model == 'CNN':
        model.add(Conv1D(64, 1, activation=activation, input_shape=(T, 1)))
        model.add(MaxPooling1D())
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(units = units, activation=activation))
    elif prediction_model == 'LSTM+CNN':
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, 1, activation=activation), input_shape = (None, T, 1)))
        model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling1D()))
        model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
        model.add(LSTM(units = units, activation=activation))
    elif prediction_model == 'MLP':
        model.add(Dense(units = units, activation=activation, input_dim=T))
    model.add(Dense(int(HORIZON)))
    model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary() 
    #model_fit = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = int(epochs), validation_data = (X_valid, y_valid), verbose = 1)
    return model
```

That's the second func:

```
def time_series_prediction_with_data_new(prediction_model, column, dataframe):
    df = pd.read_json(dataframe, orient='index')    
    if column == 'node_cpu_seconds_total':
        df = df.drop(columns = ['node_network_receive_bytes_total'])
        data_set_selection = 'node_cpu_seconds_total'
    elif column == 'node_network_receive_bytes_total':
        df = df.drop(columns = ['node_cpu_seconds_total'])
        data_set_selection = 'node_network_receive_bytes_total'
    #print(df)
    #print(len(df))
    length_df = len(df)
    train_rows = int(0.8*length_df)
    remain_rows = 200 
    valid_rows = int(0.1*length_df)
    test_rows = length_df - train_rows - valid_rows
    train = df.copy()[:train_rows]
    train_rows_new = train_rows + 1
    valid = df.copy()[train_rows:train_rows + valid_rows]
    test = df.copy()[train_rows + valid_rows:]
    #print(test.head())
    #print(len(test))
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    train[data_set_selection] = scaler.fit_transform(train)
    valid[data_set_selection] = scaler.fit_transform(valid)
    test[data_set_selection] = scaler.fit_transform(test)
    T = 2 # Let the input be a vector of the previous 30 minutes of the values.
    HORIZON = 1 # one-step-ahead prediction
    train_shifted = train.copy()
    train_shifted['y_t+1'] = train_shifted[data_set_selection].shift(-1, freq = '6s')
    for t in range(1, T+1):
        train_shifted[str(T-t)] = train_shifted[data_set_selection].shift(T-t, freq = '6s')
    y_col = 'y_t+1'
    X_cols = []
    for i in range(-T+1, 1):
        if i != 0:
            X_cols.append('t{}'.format(i))
        else:
            X_cols.append('t')
    train_shifted.columns = ['original'] + [y_col] + X_cols
    train_shifted = train_shifted.dropna(how = 'any')
    y_train = np.array(train_shifted[y_col]) 
    X_train = np.array(train_shifted[X_cols])
    subsequences = 2
    if prediction_model != 'LSTM+CNN':
        X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], T, 1)
    else:
        X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], subsequences, T, 1))
    """print(X_train.shape[0])
    print(X_train.shape[1])
    print(X_train.shape[2])"""
    valid_shifted = valid.copy()
    test_shifted = test.copy()
    valid_shifted['y_t+1'] = valid_shifted[data_set_selection].shift(-1, freq = '6s')
    test_shifted['y_t+1'] = test_shifted[data_set_selection].shift(-1, freq = '6s')
    for t in range(1, T+1):
        valid_shifted[str(T-t)] = valid_shifted[data_set_selection].shift(T-t, freq = '6s')
    for t in range(1, T+1):
        test_shifted[str(T-t)] = test_shifted[data_set_selection].shift(T-t, freq = '6s')
    valid_shifted.columns = ['original'] + [y_col] + X_cols
    test_shifted.columns = ['original'] + [y_col] + X_cols
    valid_shifted = valid_shifted.dropna(how = 'any')
    test_shifted = test_shifted.dropna(how = 'any')
    y_valid = np.array(valid_shifted[y_col])
    y_test = np.array(test_shifted[y_col])
    X_valid = np.array(valid_shifted[X_cols])
    X_test = np.array(test_shifted[X_cols])
    """print(X_valid.shape[0])
    print(X_valid.shape[1])
    print(X_test.shape[0])
    print(X_test.shape[1])"""
    if prediction_model != 'LSTM+CNN':
        X_valid = X_valid.reshape(X_valid.shape[0], T, 1)
        X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], T, 1)
    else:
        X_valid = X_valid.reshape((X_valid.shape[0], subsequences, T, 1))
        X_test = X_test.reshape((X_valid.shape[0], subsequences, T, 1))
    one_hundread_list = []

    #loss_func = 'mse'
    
    for v in range(1, 101):
        one_hundread_list.append(v)
    param_grid = {'epochs': [100], 'optimizer': ['RMSprop'], 'batch_size' : [32], 'activation' : ['relu', 'tanh']}
    model_new = KerasRegressor(build_fn=model_selection(prediction_model, T, HORIZON, activation = 'tanh'), activation = 'tanh')
    # Apply grid search
    grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model_new, param_grid=param_grid, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', n_jobs = -1)
    grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))
    # Print the best parameters and the corresponding score
    print("Best score: ", grid_result.best_score_)
    print("Best parameters found: ", grid_result.best_params_)
    epochs_sel = grid_result.best_params_['epochs']
    optimizer_sel = grid_result.best_params_['optimizer']
    batch_size_sel = grid_result.best_params_['batch_size']
    """print("Best cross-validation results: ", grid_result.cv_results_)
    print("Best mean cross-validated scores for all the parameter combinations.: ", grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score'])
    print("Best combination of hyperparameters and their corresponding values: ", grid_result.cv_results_['params'])"""
```

My code generates the following TypeError:

```
TypeError: final_build_fn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'activation'
```

How can I add activation function as hyperparameter?